# Can't find research area in my master thesis topic

Tags: research-process, thesis

I'm master computer science student. I would like to do my master thesis in a company. I got a topic from a company but the problem is when I show my topic to my professor he said he didn't find research in my topic. He said that this is normal when you take topic from a company.

I really want to do my master thesis with company because it will level up my career.

I read some papers I tell my idea about the research area but my professor tell me you are in root domain there a lot of branches.

How can I find a research area and how can I impress my prof?

Comment: It's not absolutely clear to me. Are you saying you can't find any research papers on the topic? Or that your prof won't agree to supervise you on this subject?  By the way, if it is the case there are *NO* research papers on the topic, it's exciting and scary at the same time. Uncharted territory can contain anything, good, bad, or boring.

Comment: No  there lot research things going in my topic. the problem is my topic domain very big. and my professor is tell me if you take this topic will feel like lost in space. my topic is about "**how to optimize en50128 using software development process and project management software". how to fulfill agile  methodology**.  I can't impressed prof

Answer (score 2):

Companies usually set the topics they offer for Master's thesis students, and you usually cannot come with your own topic. At least in Germany, companies pay Master's Thesis students (even though it is very much below the market rate), so they want to get something useful out of your thesis work. Sometimes (not always), they exaggerate this and make students do mostly implementation work, with very little research.

On the other hand, professors do research so they naturally prefer supervising Master's theses that are research-oriented. Some (again, not all) professors also feel that the student should learn something from the thesis, and see implementation-only theses as "providing cheap labor" to companies without the student actually learning much.

This means that, if you want to do your thesis at a company, you have two options:

- **Find another topic offered by the same or another company, which involves more research**

  This should be the preferred option if you are at all interested in doing research afterwards. There are companies that offer more research-oriented Master's theses. You can also consider a government research institution, which is more likely to offer suitable topics.
- **Find another professor that is willing to supervise your less-research-oriented topic**

  There are professors that are happy to supervise more implementation-oriented theses. You might want to look at other departments in your university that work on similar topics. This should be your preferred option if you do not want to do research afterwards or if you like the topic of the implementation-oriented thesis very much.